# Export effort and clocksum from org-mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am tracking project in with org-mode, which is working well for me.  I have all of my blocks of work scheduled out, tasks are estimated and time is tracked.

I export it ~ once a week for other people to look at, but I can't get the effort and CLOCKSUM  to show in the exported file.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can either:

- Set `org-export-with-drawers` to `t`.  This will export the drawer properties below the header.  It's exported as an example block, so if you want it to have it's own class for CSS selection, you'll have to define your own org-export-format-drawer function.  I use the following configuration:

  ```
  (setq org-export-with-drawers t)

  (defun jbd-org-export-format-drawer (name content)
    "Export drawers to drawer HTML class."
    (setq content (org-remove-indentation content))
    (format "@<div class=\"drawer\">%s@</div>\n" content))

  (setq org-export-format-drawer-function 'jbd-org-export-format-drawer)
  ```

OR

- You can [use dynamic blocks to capture the column view](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Capturing-column-view) by typing `C-c C-x i`.  This will insert a table that displays the column view that can be updated by typing `C-c C-c` while on the `#+BEGIN:` line.

I'm actually using both methods for a current project.

Comment: Note that it doesn't work with properties: "This variable doesn’t apply to properties drawers.  See ‘org-export-with-properties’ instead."

Comment: not working for me today :( `: Emacs version: GNU Emacs 26.2 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.30)
:  of 2019-04-12
: org version: 9.2.3`